# i want send all parameters of contact form in my mail body

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-views

```
def sales_inquiry(request):
    if request.method=="POST":
        name = request.POST["name"]
        company = request.POST["company"]
        email = request.POST["email"]
        contact = request.POST["contact"]

        package = request.POST["package"]
        mode = request.POST["mode"]
        pieces = request.POST["pieces"]
        gross = request.POST["gross"]

        country_origin = 'country_origin' in request.POST
        country_destination = request.POST["country_destination"]
        port_origin = request.POST["port_origin"]
        port_destination = request.POST["port_destination"]
        commodity = request.POST["commodity"]

        container = request.POST["container"]
        length = request.POST["length"]
        height = request.POST["height"]
        width = request.POST["width"]
        send_mail('Inquiry form', name, settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
        ['17201073suchan@viva-technology.org'], fail_silently=False)
    return render(request,'laxmi/sales_inquiry.html')
```

now i am able to send only name in my mail body but
i want to send this all attributes of this inquiry form to my mail id how should i make dict or any other option to send this whole content

Comment: why is javascript tagged?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two ways,

create a multiline string and insert html inside of that, like this,

```
html = '''
<body>
<h2>''' + name + '''</h2><p>''' + company + '''</p></body>'''
```

and then send the html instead of name

or,

you can send it like this

```
body = "name: " name + '\n' + "company: " + company
send_mail('Inquiry form',  body, settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER,
        ['17201073suchan@viva-technology.org'], fail_silently=False)
```

Comment: wouldn't a fstring be better for readability

Comment: oh sorry, I missed that out, yeah sure you can, but remember to use \n and \t in your string, \n means next line, \t means tab over